# ffmpeg time format : what does ".80" mean in 00:05:25.80 for ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg shows  an video duration is `00:05:25.80`, what does ".80" mean in ffmpeg ?

Is it possible for ffmpeg to return the video duration in seconds rather than this format ?

Comment: Wild guess: Fractions of a second…?

Comment: @OrangeDog how do you know that ? can you give a reference ?

Comment: @iMath a reference for how decimal points work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does ".80" mean in ffmpeg?

Same as it does everywhere else, eight tenths and zero hundredths.
That is, the full duration is five minutes and twenty-five point eight seconds.

> Is it possible for ffmpeg to return the video duration in seconds?

[`ffprobe`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration) uses seconds by default. What you're looking at in there in `ffmpeg` is just information for human convenience.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
325.800000
```

Comment: After read about these two sections, 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Timeunitsyntax
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration  and also Checked with ffprobe, I am sure you are right